# Question about definition of $||\cdot||_{\infty}$

Tags: measure-theory

In my measure theory course, given $(X,{\cal M},\mu)$ a measure space, for $f : X \to \mathbb{C}$ measurable, a.e. defined.

Define $||f||_{\infty} = \inf\{M \ge 0: |f| \le M \quad a.e.\}$

In some references, I have seen an argument as follows:

Given $\epsilon \in (0,||f||_{\infty})$, set $E = \{x \in X : |f(x)| \ge ||f||_{\infty} - \epsilon\}$, then $\mu(E) > 0$

Can someone explain how to verify this ? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that $\mu(E)=0$, then for all $x\in X-E$, we have $|f(x)|\leq\|f\|_{\infty}-\epsilon$, since $E$ is $\mu$-null, we have $\|f\|_{\infty}\leq\|f\|_{\infty}-\epsilon$, and this is a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

The point is that if $\mu(E)$ was $0$, you'd have $f \le \|f\|_\infty - \epsilon$ a.e., so $\|f\|_\infty$ would not be the infimum.